# How to determine the time of periastron passage (T) of a single lined spectroscopic binary?

Tags: binary-star, orbital-elements, radial-velocity

I am working on finding spectroscopic elements of a single lined spectroscopic binary. All I have is irregularly spaced radial velocity data which needs to be phase folded to plot a velocity curve (RV vs Time from T). For phase folding I need orbital period P and time of periastron passage T. I have determined the period by plotting a Lomb-Scargle periodogram but I'm unable to find a method to determine T. I can use already published value of T for that spectroscopic binary, but I want to learn how to determine T myself. Is there any method to determine T from RV data?

Comment: You need to fit the RV curve. One of the free parameters can be time of periastron. NB. You can only get this if there's significant eccentricity!

Comment: @ProfRob Thanks for the help! This was very easy but I completely missed it . Basically one can fit the equation $$V = V_{com} + K\left[e \cos(\omega) \pm \sin\left(2\pi\frac{(t - T)}{P}\right)\right]$$ to the RV data, where the $\pm$ sign refers to the primary or secondary component and $t$ is the time of observation. Since $P$ is known, the parameters $V_{com}$, $K$, $e$, $\omega$ and $T$ can be determined via the fit.

Comment: Yes, that is how it is done AFAIK.